# Update field object inside array javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object as array which is store in variable

```
0 : {option: "E", primary: "primary", color: "#4CAF50"}
1 : {option: "B", primary: "primary", color: "#4CAF50"}
2 : {option: "", color: "", primary: ""}
3 : {option: "", color: "", primary: ""}
4 : {option: "", color: "", primary: ""}
5 : {option: "", color: "", primary: ""}
```

My question how can I update specific key object without change at all 
this is my code

```
handleChange = (index, option) => {

    let navNumber = this.state.navNumber
    navNumber[index] = {
      option:option,
      primary:'primary',
      color:'#4CAF50'
    }

    this.setState({navNumber})

  };

  changeRagu = (index) => { 

    let navNumber = this.state.navNumber    
    navNumber[index] = navNumber[index].color = '#FF9800' 
    this.setState({navNumber})

  }
```

All I want is to update only **color** by specific **index** without make all color still empty become same

Comment: You have an array of objects, lets say your array is called test, why can't you do:  test[0]['color'] = "#ff0000";

Comment: @SPlatten i don't get it what do you mean, please elaborate more sir ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
let navNumber = this.state.navNumber
```

is bad because you are copying the reference to the `navNumber` variable, rather than creating a copy of it. As a consequence, any changes you do to `navNumber` is basically a change to `this.state.navNumber`. This means that you are mutating the state directly!

Instead try this:

```
changeRagu = (index) => { 
  let navNumber = this.state.navNumber.slice();  //make a copy of navNumber    
  let obj = Object.assign({}, navNumber[index]);  //now copy the object at index
  obj.color = '#FF9800'
  navNumber[index] = obj
  this.setState({navNumber});
}
```

Comment: An array of objects is, technically, an array of _object references_. You've successfully copied the array of references, but the references are still the same.

Comment: @Cerbrus, that should do it :)

Comment: Thanks Chris, it give me pain googling more than one hours, my question why i should copy the variable state instead using existing variable,

Comment: @FreddySidauruk [Because that is the way you are supposed to work with react state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)

Comment: @FreddySidauruk I explain that above. If you do `let navNumber = this.state.navNumber` and then do `navNumber = 123` that means that automatically this also happens `this.state.navNumber = 123`. It is anti-pattern to mutate `this.state` directly without using `this.setState()`.